# How was I able to log into a restricted FTP server with no authentication?

Tags: security, ftp, privacy

Sorry if this is off-topic.  I think an understanding of what is going on might shed light on the nature of the FTP protocol and securing FTP servers.  Basically what happened was, I logged onto a non-anonymous FTP server anonymously.  When I logged in using the regular mode (non-anonymous), it prompted me for a username and password.  But when I did an anonymous login, it didn't prompt for any authentication information.  It just let me right in.  Not too strange; I mean, some FTP servers have an authenticated mode and an anonymous mode.  But I kind of got the feeling that I wasn't supposed to be able to do that, because my session looked something like this:

```
    bash-3.2$ ftp -a download.nvidia.com
    Connected to 32940.ftp.download.akadns.net.
    220 spftp/1.0.0000 Server [216.151.177.71]
    331 Password required for USER.
    230-
    230- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    230- WARNING:  This is a restricted access system.  If you do not have explicit
    230-           permission to access this system, please disconnect immediately!
    230 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Remote system type is UNIX.
    ftp> ls
    227 Entering Passive Mode. (216,151,177,71,205,241)
    150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /.
    drwxrwxr-x   1     1994     1994        0 Jun 20 19:11 CUDAOpen64
    226 Transfer Complete
    ftp> cd CUDAOpen64
    250 CWD command successful.
    ftp> ls
    227 Entering Passive Mode. (216,151,177,71,234,111)
    150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /CUDAOpen64.
```

Kinda odd.  It seems either they didn't secure their server properly, or they did, and I just walked into a honeypot.  Or maybe this is just an inherent weakness in FTP.  I need help understanding this.  No, I'm not asking for advice on how to do black-hat hacking.  I just want to understand what's going on.

Comment: The best way to find out in this situation is to contact the administrators. A properly configured and secured FTP server will not allow anonymous users to connect. Like you stated, though, it is possible the admins allow anonymous access into a chrooted environment (possible with download only capability)

Comment: Which version of `ftp` client do you have? My `ftp` doesn't recognise the option `-a`. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: It logs in anonymously, so you don't need authentication.

Answer (score 2):

That is an anonymous FTP server.

Anonymous doesn't mean "no user" or "null user", it means "anonymous user", as in the username passed to the FTP server is the word "anonymous" (or sometimes the word "ftp"). Web browsers and FTP clients will pass the username "anonymous" to an FTP server with a password like "anon@localhost", or something to similar effect.

If you run a tcpdump or packet capture on your client machine you should see that the username being passed to the FTP server is the word "anonymous" or "ftp" with a password like the one I described above.

Here's a packet capture of me opening the same FTP site in IE. I was not prompted for a username and password but you can see that IE provided them for me.

[image]

[image]

Here's how Dreamhost explains it:

**Anonymous FTP is an FTP service that does not require a unique username and password to log in. Any user can log in using the username "anonymous" and typically use their email address as the password.**

Here's how Microsoft explains it:

**Anonymous users will typically log in by using a user name of ftp or anonymous, and most users will use their e-mail address as a password.**